# Do not generate blazor css isolation suffix for :root variables

Tags: css, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

A blazor component with css isolation (`MyComponent.razor.css`) can define variables like so:

```css
.my-component {
  --width: 5rem;
  --padding: 2px;
}
```

That would be scoped to the component: it will be unusable anywhere else.

One could also do this:

```css
:root {
  --mc-width: 5rem;
  --mc-padding: 2px;
}
```

But although one would expect that to be available to other components too, it won't - because it will be rendered with a css isolation suffix, e.g. `:root[d-b3a7ca5e3a]`.

That doesn't work well with UI libraries.

For example, bootstrap has styles scoped to a particular widget (e.g. accordion, menu, tabs), and styles scoped globally (`:root`). Root styles are useful so that your code can take widgets' properties into account in your layout.

A workaround is to redefine everything in a global `app.css` (thus avoiding the css isolation suffix); but that creates duplication, and one loses encapsulation.

Can I generate `:root` styles with css isolation, but without the isolation suffix?

Comment: From the [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0), I think what you want is unavaiable.

Comment: @XiaotianYang Sadly, I think you are right. Maybe in a future version.